# react-navigation more than one nesting

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this structure:

- Main

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

    - Grandchild 1
- Other

The problem that I'm having is that I can't navigate from Child 2 to Grandchild 1. It throws

**TypeError: navigation.navigate is not a function**

or

**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.navigate')**

I have a stack navigator like this:

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Main" />
    <Stack.Screen name="Child2" />
    <Stack.Screen name="Grandchild" />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

I can go from Main to Child2, do I have to make a new Stack for deeper nesting?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the navigation.navigate in the wrong place

It should be used in Component

```
<Child onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Grandchild');} />
```

And then inside the component Touchable do:

```
<Touchable onPress={props.onPress}>
...
</Touchable>
```